# XSLT: analyze-string, replace on regular expressions

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is a follow-up for this question:
[XSLT: analyze-string on text with children nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52560281/xslt-analyze-string-on-text-with-children-nodes/52640116#52640116)

I am trying to use analyze-string on elements that possibly contain children nodes. Here is a snippet of a source file:

```
    <year>
         1975 music
     </year>
     <year>
         1985<genre>rock</genre>music
     </year>
     <year>
         2005 music
     </year>
```

Here is now the next exercise. With the same xml input, I would like to add attributes:

```
    <year decade="7">
         70's music
     </year>
     <year decade="8">
         80's<genre>rock</genre> music
     </year>
```

Do I need the analyze-string ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a template that matches `year` which can get the text node containing the year, and extract the relevant digit from it, to create the decade

Try this template

```
<xsl:template match="year">
  <xsl:variable name="text" select="normalize-space(text()[matches(., $pattern)])" />
  <year decade="{replace($text, concat('.*', $pattern, '.*'), '$1')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </year>
</xsl:template>
```